# I must avoid entering letters on my digipas

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a small problem. When I enter a new transfert of 269 euros with the account bank  number BE072750044-35066. I have to introduce a code of confirmation. The code is `350269`.

[image]

The figures `350` are the last 5 figures of the bank account number -> BE072750044-**350**66.
And the 269 represents the amount for the new transfert.

Another example, if the new transfert was of 350 euros. We will have `350350`.

[image]

Now my problem, if I have an account bank with a letter at the end. FR5940802053780006178110**K**61.

The problem is that I retrieve `10K269`, but the user must enter only numbers on the digipas.
How to avoid this problem for the user, please?

[image]

```
getTokenTwoAdd(nt) {
    var partOne, partTwo, absoluteAmount;
    partOne = (nt.iban.substr(nt.iban.length - 5)).substring(0, 3);
    absoluteAmount = Math.abs(nt.amount);
    absoluteAmount = parseInt(absoluteAmount);
    partTwo = ((absoluteAmount < 100) ? this.helpers.addLeadingZeroesLeft(absoluteAmount, 3) : absoluteAmount) + "";
    partTwo = partTwo.substring(0, 3);
    console.log("Iban number, slice => " + partOne);
    console.log("Iban number => " + nt.iban);
    console.log("Amount => " + absoluteAmount);

    return partOne + partTwo;
}
```

The variable `partOne` represents the account bank number with the slice

The variable `nt.iban` is the accout bank number

The variable `absoluteAmount` is the amount for the new transfert

[image]

Comment: So what do you expect to happen when there is a letter in the last three characters of the bank account?

Comment: @trincot: I would like to replace default figures, is it possible? But, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add exactly what you want to put in the display for that given example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of any characters that are not digits, you could use

```js
partOne = nt.iban.replace(/\D+/g, '').substr(-5, 3);
```

where `\D+` matches one or more non-digit characters.

Comment: The above answer assumes you want the first three digits of the last five digits in the string.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly.